# Get file name by CMD

Tags: cmd.exe

I have this code:

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /s /b sqlncli*.msi') do set "name=%%a"
```

which gives me the full path of the file.

What I need from this is not full path, only the file name.

How I can extract it from the full path?

Comment: `%%~na` or `%%~nxa`. Please read _entire_ `for /?`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### I need from this Full Path, only the File Name.

> for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /s /b sqlncli*.msi') do set "name=%%a"

Use the `%~n` operator:

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /s /b sqlncli*.msi') do set "name=%%~na"
```

If you want the filename and the extension, use the  `%~nx` operator:

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /s /b sqlncli*.msi') do set "name=%%~nxa"
```

> `%~n1` Expand `%1` to a file Name without file extension or path - `MyFile`
>   or if only a path is present, with no trailing backslash, the last folder in that path.
>
> `%~x1` Expand `%1` to a file eXtension only - `.txt`

Source [parameters](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html) - A command line argument (or parameter) is any value passed into a batch script.

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line | SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/)
- [Windows CMD Commands (categorized) - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/commands.html)
- [parameters](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html) - A command line argument (or parameter) is any value passed into a batch script.

Comment: How to put the search of file names to variables, I mean If I got 2 file names, I put the first in variable and the other name in other variable.

Comment: @AbdullahAbualkher Use a counter.